# TFS Excel Add-In: Change Query Source Programatically / Macro

Tags: vba, excel, tfs

I would like to change TFS Excel Add-in List Query programmatically using excel macro.

I have requirement to provide bulk edit work items functionality using ASP.Net Web Application. I am planning to create pre-defined excel template (Bind with Empty TFS Query) and copying it to web server. I am creating TFS Query programmatically based on user input (work item id) and downloading this template file on client when user request "Bulk Edit" functionality. I want to run macro which will update TFS Excel Query and refresh list pragmatically. I tried sample app to refresh TFS Excel list (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/team_foundation/2010/11/06/programming-for-the-tfs-excel-add-in/) which is helpful but I would also like to change "List Query". I also tried accessing TFS Excel custom properties to change connection string or query but not sure which property and how? I need input for following items

1. Change TFS Excel Add-in List Query programmatically using excel
   macro OR
2. Update TFS Excel Custom Property to update Server / Query
   name and refresh list

Answer (score 0):

Well, there really is no supported allready prepared way to do that. Here is the official doc from MSDN: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel

Comment: I understand that this functionality is not available in web acess and hence want to provide custom solution where Excel Macro will change TFS Query programatically. Macro will run when user opens XL file on client, assuming client already installed TFS Excel Add-In.  There are sample available to refresh TFS Query List but I would also like to change TFS Query which is bind with XL template.